# Remove user inputbox and replace with yesterday's date (automate process)

Tags: ms-access, datepicker

I have the following code and have been asked to remove the user input box and automate pulling in files. One issue is if the current day is Monday, we would need Friday's date pulled in (not yesterday).  I am sorry for being extremely basic, but I believe I would need to replace `InputBox("Input Date")` with something like `DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 1, GETDATE()), 0)` - but it does not like `Day` or `DD`.

Any ideas? (and thank you for being patient with me in advance)

```vb
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False
 Dim InvDateStr As String
 Dim InvDate As Date
 Dim Directory_Sheets As String
 Dim filename_sheets As String
 Dim db As Database
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
 Dim startdate As Date
 Dim EndDate As Date

'startdate = #9/23/2010#
'enddate = #1/12/2011#
'InvDate = startdate

'Do Until InvDate = enddate
 InvDateStr = InputBox("Input Date")
 If InvDateStr = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
InvDate = CDate(InvDateStr)
Directory_Sheets = FilePath & "Inventory_Surveys\"

On Error Resume Next
' Pull Stores with Inventory
```

Comment: Subtract a day with `DateAdd("d", -1, inputDate)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only going to do the date part, you can implement it:

```vb
InvDate = Date - 1 'Yesterday
Do While Weekday(InvDate, vbMonday) > 5 'Saturday or Sunday
   InvDate = InvDate - 1
Loop
```

Comment: Erik - Thank you very much - that worked. Much appreciated!